# Make Raster Layer with Overlapping Images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, layers

I am trying to set up a template which will display different maps based on layer definitions. One of the layers is a raster layer. Is it possible to combine a number of overlapping images into a single layer so specific images can be selected with a definition query?

Comment: One of catalogues (managed ?) even supports data driven pages definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with a [Mosaic Dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-a-mosaic-dataset.htm):

> A mosaic dataset allows you to store, manage, view, and query small to
>   vast collections of raster and image data. It is a data model within
>   the geodatabase used to manage a collection of raster datasets
>   (images) stored as a catalog and viewed as a mosaicked image

Example:

[image]

Comment: Nice. I'd been searching for a good example under Mosaic Dataset and Raster Catalog - at least I know Mosaic Dataset will work. Our corporate firewall blocks your image (yes really!). Can you point me to a relevant tutorial example?

Comment: @nealei follow the link i provided